# Maintain Fixed Number Of Threads always

Tags: java, thread-safety, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am creating fixed thread pool from the executor service. But if some run time exception or error(OutOfMemory Error) comes then the thread will dead and the number of threads will keep on decreasing and at one time number of thread will be zero, which is known as silent thread killing.

One way is to catch throwable ( which is not a good practice) to avoid thread kill. Is there any way we can maintain the fixed number of threads always. If the thread kills/dies then a new thread should automatically spawn so that we have fixed number of threads always.

Any suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a silent thread kill? I cannot reproduce it. I've updated the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24697277/3080094) to throw an `OutOfMemoryError` at the end of the first `Runnable` but the program still runs fine - the `ThreadPoolExecutor` simply discards the 'old' thread and creates a new one.

Comment: @vanOekel Are you sure that ThreadPool Executor Creates the new one when old thread dies. I never find this anywhere. Any link would really be very helpful.

Comment: Well the updated code shows it happens. So let's turn it around: can you show that a `ThreadPoolExecutor` does NOT start a new thread when one of the threads in the pool is no longer usable, or provide a link to documentation that explains when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The ApiDocs for the [`SingleThreadExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) state the following: "Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks."

This appears to apply also to ThreadPools with several threads (see demo program below). So unless the program runs inro a real `OutOfMemoryError` (e.g. not an accidental one where a much too large byte-array is allocated), the silent thread kills will not happen. If the program runs into a real `OutOfMemoryError` then I do not think much can be done: all kinds of statements that must be executed (in final blocks) can suddenly fail to execute due to being out of memory and that can leave the program in an inconsistent state (like a ThreadPool without threads).

The demo program below shows all tasks are executed and the thead-names show new threads are created by the ThreadPool:

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SilentKillThread {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        new SilentKillThread().runTest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static int MAX_TASKS = 3;
static long SLEEP_TIME_MS = 400;

AtomicInteger tasksDoneCount = new AtomicInteger();

public void runTest() throws Exception {

    ThreadPoolExecutor tp = new ThreadPoolExecutor(MAX_TASKS, MAX_TASKS,
            60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TASKS; i++) {
        tp.execute(new FailingTask());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TASKS; i++) {
        tp.execute(new SleepingTask());
    }
    tp.shutdown();
    if (tp.awaitTermination(SLEEP_TIME_MS * 4, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        System.out.println("Finished");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Finished but threadpool still active.");
    }
    System.out.println("Tasks done: " + tasksDoneCount.get());
}

class FailingTask implements Runnable {

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        String tname = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(tname + " Sleeping");
        try { Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_MS); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();} 
        int tcount = tasksDoneCount.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println(tname + " Done sleeping " + tcount);
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    }
}

class SleepingTask implements Runnable {

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        String tname = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(tname + " Sleeping");
        try { Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_MS); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();} 
        int tcount = tasksDoneCount.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println(tname + " Done sleeping " + tcount);
    }
}
}
```